# assembly file not found in asp.net project

Tags: asp.net, web-config, devexpress

I am trying to use the devexpress.xpo assembly in my asp.net project but I am having trouble adding it to my project. I have added an assembly reference in my applications web.config(see below) and when I run the application on my development machine (vs 2010 iis express 7.5) everything works fine. However when I deploy the application to our production server (iis 6.0) I get the following error:

```
 Could not load file or assembly 'DevExpress.Xpo.v9.1' or one of its dependencies. The   system cannot find the file specified.
```

The development machine has the assembly installed in the GAC but the production server has not. I have added the DevExpress.Xpo reference via visual studios add reference function so the DevExpress.Xpo.v9.1.dll file is copied to my applications bin folder.

My web.config:

```
 <configuration>
      <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
          <assemblies>
            <add assembly="DevExpress.Xpo.v9.1"/>
          </assemblies>
        </compilation>
        <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
      </system.web>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: Check out DevExpress documentation for installation to see if it needs to be installed in the GAC...

Comment: Installing it to production servers GAC is not an option.(It would conflict with another devexpress version allready installed there)

Comment: GAC is supposed to allow multiple versions of the same DLL - I understand why you want to keep it local, but I don't understand why it would conflict....

Comment: Could this be a trust issue?  I could be wrong, but I think the DLL, being local, would require the application to have full trust.

Answer (score 2):

Search applications bin folder on production server for DevExpress.Xpo and DevExpress.Data dlls. You need to have both dlls there since DevExpress.Xpo won't work without DevExpress.Data.

Also, look here for discussion about "choosing" between Bin folder and GAC dlls:
http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q230929.aspx

Comment: I have both ddls in my bin folder. I also tried adding the devexpress.data assembly in my web config and it produced the exact same error just on devexpress.data assembly.

Comment: Can you try with complete reference like this (sample is for another version):   <add assembly="DevExpress.Data.v10.2, Version=10.2.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" />

Comment: I tried the complete reference approach but I still get the same error message.

Comment: My last try: Can you remove all devexpress assemblies from web.config?

Answer (score 1):

Copy assembly files (Web.config's entries registered within the "**assemblies**" section http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfyb45k1.aspx) required for each used product / suite ("**Deployment - General Information**") within the **GAC** or "**Bin**" folder.

This approach is common for any 3-rd party tools http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178610%28v=vs.80%29.aspx.